# How do the local variables in an async function affect the type of its future?

Tags: rust, async-await, future

I encountered a strange error. Here's a MRE:

```rust
async fn do_nothing() { }

async fn use_dyn_read() {
    let read: &dyn std::io::Read = & (&[0 as u8; 1] as &[u8]);
    do_nothing().await;
}

#[tokio::main]
fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(use_dyn_read());
}
```

When I compile I get an error with this message:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:10:18
    |
10  |     tokio::spawn(use_dyn_read());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future returned by `use_dyn_read` is not `Send`
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn std::io::Read`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src/main.rs:5:17
    |
4   |     let read: &dyn std::io::Read = & (&[0 as u8; 1] as &[u8]);
    |         ---- has type `&dyn std::io::Read` which is not `Send`
5   |     do_nothing().await;
    |                 ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `read` maybe used later
6   | }
    | - `read` is later dropped here
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> /home/jrpear/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.21.2/src/task/spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

`future is not 'Send' as this value is used across an await` means that the type of local variables in an async function affect the type of its future.

<s>However, some non-`Send` types don't cause this error. Using a `Cell` instead of a `&dyn Read` doesn't cause this error.</s> Edit: I was wrong, `Cell` *is* `Send` (but not `Sync`)

What's going on here?

Comment: Most async executors are multithreaded. So spawned task could be running on one thread, then yield, and then be picked up by another thread. This yielding can happen anytime you await some future.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Yeah it makes sense why the future needs to be `Send`. I don't understand when and why the future is not `Send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, any local variable that is in-scope before and after an `.await` must be able to be persisted in the generated `Future` and will therefore affect its traits like `Send` and `Sync`. Here are some examples that demonstrate this:

```
struct IsSend;
struct NotSend(*const ()); // pointers are not Send

async fn is_send() {
    // This local variable is in scope across an await-point and is Send, so the
    // Future returned by this async function can also be Send.
    let _is = IsSend;
    futures::future::ready(()).await;
}

async fn not_send() {
    // This local variable is in scope across an await-point and is not Send, so
    // the Future returned by this async function can not be Send.
    let _not = NotSend(&());
    futures::future::ready(()).await;
}

async fn is_also_send() {
    {
        // This local variable is not Send but is not in scope across an await-
        // point, so Future returned by this async function can still be Send.
        let _not = NotSend(&());
    }
    futures::future::ready(()).await;
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(is_send());
    // this does not compile since tokio::spawn requires Send
    // tokio::spawn(not_send()); 
    tokio::spawn(is_also_send());
}
```

The `Cell` type *does* implement `Send` (as long as its inner value is `Send`).

One thing that's tricky to remember is that *references* only implement `Send` if their referee implements `Sync`. In essence, a type being `Sync` means that it can be accessed from a different thread. So if it is `Sync` then its reference is `Send` since it can be sent to another thread and still refer to the original.

Trait objects are comparatively easier to understand, they only express the traits that they advertise. So a `dyn Read` does *not* implement `Send` or `Sync` since it doesn't say it does. So that coupled with our reference rules means that `read` needs to be `&dyn Read + Sync` in order to implement `Send` so it can be used across the `.await` while allowing the `Future` to implement `Send`.

Answer (score 1):

`dyn` types implement *only* the traits that are explicitly written in them (and their supertraits).  You don't get to automatically take advantage of trait implementations of the concrete type you're using, which is what happens in Rust code that doesn't use `dyn`. Instead, you have to pick the traits that will be exposed (and, equally, the traits that will be required of the concrete type).

You wrote `dyn Read`, so it doesn't implement `Sync`. Change it to `dyn Read + Sync` and the program compiles.

```rust
async fn use_dyn_read() {
    let read: &(dyn std::io::Read + Sync) = & (&[0 as u8; 1] as &[u8]);
    do_nothing().await;
}
```

(The reason we're writing `Sync`, not `Send`, is because we need the future to be `Send`, so we need the `&dyn ...` to be `Send`, and the rule for a immutable reference being `Send` is that the referent must be `Sync` — because an immutable reference grants *shared* access. However, in order to actually use this `Read`, you'll want to change the `&` to `&mut`, at which point you'll need `+ Send` instead of `+ Sync`.)